# git: Get all the committed hashes from a specific branch

Tags: git

Lets assume that I have a branch called A and I committed my changes 5 times,
how can I get all the 5 hashes from branch A,

```
git log
```

its not helping because its from long time ago and I cant find it...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The notation `..` allows to see commits from `A` that are not in `master`, that is the commits that only belong to master.

```
git log master..A
```

To get only the hashes use the `--format=%H` option to this command.

Answer (score 3):

It's a little difficult to understand what you mean, but if you are asking how can I show the last 5 commits on my branch ...

then you can simply specify how many commits you want to see

```
git log -5
```

or if you prefer to see it on just one line per commit

```
git log --oneline -5
```

if you want to see what commits are in branch A but not yet merged into master

```
git log master..A
```